# Bootstrap Popover Close on Any Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see from this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/10/), I have a Boostrap Popover that is able to close with an outside click as well as with a click on the "x."

However, when you click on another button popover, the first popover does not disappear.

Is there a way to change the javascript so that the first popover disappears on any click?

HTML:

```
<form action="quote-calculator.php" method="post">

<div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
  <a href="#" class="more-info btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
</div>

<div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
  <a href="#" class="more-info btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
</div>

<div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
  <a href="#" class="more-info btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
</div>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
    var isVisible = false;
    var clickedAway = false;

    $('.btn-danger').popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual'
        }).click(function(e) {
            $(this).popover('show');
        $('.popover-content').append('<button class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 6px;">&times;</button>');
            clickedAway = false
            isVisible = true
            e.preventDefault()
        });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(isVisible & clickedAway)
      {
        $('.btn-danger').popover('hide')
        isVisible = clickedAway = false
      }
      else
      {
        clickedAway = true
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
$('.popover').hide();
```

before

```
$(this).popover('show');
```

This hides all `popover` class elements before showing the current one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
$('.close:visible').trigger('click');
```

before

```
$(this).popover('show');
```

<kbd>[Updated Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/12/)</kbd>

Comment: It does close the first popover but sometimes it also closes the second popover also.